# ES6 getter/method without curly braces

Tags: javascript, typescript, methods, ecmascript-6, getter

I have some classes which consist of many short getters/methods.

Example:

```
get jQuery() {
  return this.pageConfig.jQuery || jQuery;
}
```

An arrow function with similar content may be written as follows:

```
() => this.pageConfig.jQuery || jQuery;
```

Which is a one-liner and thus consumes only 1/3 of vertical space.

**But it is not a getter nor a method.**

Is there a recommended way of writing getters/methods in the form of a one-liner? **(if possible without curly braces and without the `return` keyword)**

My getters and methods need not modify the object. They are just reading.

Comment: Generally, you do not want to define methods using arrow syntax because then you will not get the value of `this` to point to the object which is what you want for methods on an object.  Remember, arrow functions are not only a syntax shortcut, they also use the lexical `this` which is not what you want for methods on an object.

Comment: Your first example can be collapsed onto one line if that's all you're after.  Just keep the braces and the `return` and put it all on one line.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Nice one-liner solution:

```
readonly jQuery = this.pageConfig.jQuery || jQuery
```

It is short, behaves like you would expect it from the getter, and needs no curly braces.

Comment: Strictly speaking this answer is *incorrect*.

The behavior of this code is not equivalent to a getter in two ways:

1. It will be evaluated as soon as the file is evaluated, rather than when the getter is accessed. If `this.pageConfig.jQuery` gets set _after_ page/file load, then the fallback to `jQuery` will happen incorrectly.
2. If the getter has side effects (e.g counting the number of times that it has been accessed), then the side effect will only happen once, as opposed to every time the accessor is accessed.

Comment: Both your points are true yet not relevant if best practices are not violated: jQuery should not be set (that would violate the immutability principle) and getters with side effects should not be the norm. However, if counting is needed, just take the ES6 getter.

Answer (score 5):

For a one liner, just go with this:

```
get jQuery() {return this.pageConfig.jQuery || jQuery;}
```

Arrow functions are not for method definitions because they use the lexical `this`, whereas a method wants the object `this`.  Remember that while arrow functions are a nice shorthand, they also affect the value of `this` in a way that is not usually compatible with method definitions.

Answer (score 4):

No, there is nothing shorter than ( you can skip the `;` )

```
get jQuery() { return this.pageConfig.jQuery || jQuery }
```

**A bit more explanation**

You can't use the arrow function ( `() => this.pageConfig.jQuery || jQuery` ), because for one it is not a getter function and `this` doesn't refer to the context of the object but the context of execution (which could be the object but doesn't have to.

There is/was the `__defineGetter__` function ( [some documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/__defineGetter__) ) which allows you to define a getter. It is now deprecated and probably would be even more complex than the `get`. But as the docs say, it's used widely and will probably never get removed.

Luckily for you: I'm all for crazy solutions

```js
class Test {
  
  constructor() {
    this.pageConfig = {}
    this.pageConfig.jQuery = "value"
    
    let properties = {
      'jQuery': () => this.pageConfig.jQuery || "Default",
      'text': () => this.pageConfig.text || "Default"
    }
    for(let prop in properties) this.__defineGetter__(prop, properties[prop])
    
  }
  
}

let t = new Test
console.log(t.jQuery)
console.log(t.text)
```

Happy one lining ( but honestly just use the `get` from ECMA 5 )

Comment: Crazy solution. I like :-D

Answer (score -1):

I was thinking of building a babel library to handle this
I think something like this would look fancy

```
const weekDays = [
            {
                day: 'Sunday',
                get input() {
                    return TimeRange(this.day)
                }
                // something like this
                // get input() => TimeRange(this.day)
            }
]
```