# Single line shortform for non-arrow function?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

Sometimes, mostly in classes, I need to do a single line function.

For instance:

```
class Blah {
    getVisibilityAnimValue() { return this.state.isVisible ? 100 : 0 }
}
```

In ES6 is there is any friendly way? I tried to omit the surrounding curlies and omitting the return but it's not working.

Comment: Non-arrow function? Why?

Comment: Related: [ES6 getter/method without curly braces](https://stackoverflow.com/q/42540301/1048572)

Comment: The ES6 method definition syntax already *is* much more friendly than the ES5 `Blah.prototype.getVisibilityAnimValue = function() { … };`

Comment: @Kinduser Doing a `=>` just for shortform sakes results in an useless `.bind` right (if i did not need access to `this`)?

Comment: I don't think an arrow function really does a "useless bind".  I think it's a feature built into interpreter that every arrow function has a `this` value associated with it at definition from it's scope context.  Yes, I supposed they could use `.bind()` for it, but I suspect it's lower level than that.  Rather than associate the `this` value from how it is called (as the interpreter would do for a normal function), it uses the `this` value that is associated with it's lexical scope context.  Basically, the interpreter is going to assign a `this` value - it's just a matter of which one.

Comment: Thank you very much @jfriend00 for such an indepth comment!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> In ES6 is there is any friendly way?

No, there is not.  As I think you already know, in order to use `this` to refer to the calling instance, you cannot use an arrow function (which uses the lexical `this` rather than a `this` based on how it was called).  So, you have to use a conventional ES6 method definition.  As such, you need the braces `{}` and you need the `return`.

The ES6 class syntax at least saves you the ES5 scheme of:

```
Blah.prototype.getVisibilityAnimValue = function() {...}
```

> I tried to omit the surrounding curlies and omitting the return but it's not working.

Yep, those are still required.

---

If you had a lot of methods that worked just like this and used the identical logic, you could factor the logic into a shared function.

```
// define this once and then use it many places
function zVal(val) {
     return val ? 0 : 100;
}

getVisibilityAnimValue() { return zVal(this.state.isVisible) }
```

But, for something this simple, it's arguable whether this is "better" since it now involves an extra function call and makes it a little harder to see (in a glance) what it does.

Comment: Thank you jfriend for an in-depth answer.

Answer (score 1):

No. That is one of the exact reasons why arrow functions were created.

Comment: And yet, arrow functions can't be used here because the OP needs access to `this`.

Comment: Thanks @4castle yes I needed this. I guess I can re-bind it in the constructor. Doesn't arrow functions have extra overhead of doing the binding in babel etc?